# Editing formulas with Unicode symbols

Tags: discussion, mathjax, formatting, equation, unicode

Should the questions with Unicode symbols in formulas be edited?

I'm asking this based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260119/f-continous-at-x-0-lim-h0-x-0x-0h-fracfth-fx-0) question. Look in the [source code](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4adf6032-c46f-42a3-9aa8-d097a678f6bb/view-source) to see what I mean.

Comment: No! Unicode is the future...

Comment: What's wrong with having Unicode characters in posts? I use them all the time in my posts. (I don't use Unicode math symbols but rather symbols like “ ” — « ».)

Comment: I have a pretty low threshhold for editing posts—I go around adjusting the spacing and the heights of the parentheses in formulas—but even I wouldn't bother to replace a literal ε with `\epsilon`.

Comment: If it looks good, I don't see why we should bother. The only case I can see for editing is if the OP used literal ε one place and `\epsilon` another, and the two don't look the same....

Comment: I like using unicode math symbols. I find it easier to "scan" the code with unicode symbols and I use hotstrings to type them fast. Which problem could unicode symbols give ?

Comment: Perhaps @m0nhawk should say what problem he or she thinks is being addressed here?

Comment: Not sure if it's related but [it seems that Firefox has some trouble with one of the fonts it uses for mathematical Unicode characters.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4819/19341)