# How can I typeset blackboard bold numbers?

Tags: support, mathjax, typesetting

How can I typeset blackboard bold numbers? What I need is simply something like $\mathbb A$ (`\mathbb{A}`) but with `A` replaced numbers. With Miktex I can import the bbm package and use `\mathbbm 1`. But this seems impossible with Mathjax.

---

Reply to Calvin Khor:

On my computer `\mathbb` doesn't work for numbers. Below is a screenshot of your exact answer:

---

### Image starts here

[image]

### Image ends here

---

You see that on the first line where you wrote "rendered code" I see plain numbers. Not sure why. It could be because of the platform. I am using Win10 with Chrome.

Comment: I'm a little confused, does `\mathbb{1234567890}`$\mathbb{1234567890}$ give nothing? It works for me, I'll upload a screenshot https://imgur.com/yYaKLl8

Comment: @CalvinKhor It's weird. I see only plain numbers on my computer. But the ones given by unicode does work. See my edited question.

Comment: All my Math.SE life thus far I've been using `\mathbb 1` unaware of this issue... I believe the "MathJax tutorial" doesn't mention anything, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference , there seems to be a similar issue for lowercase letters https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28930/lower-case-blackboard-bold-displays-inconsistently , a tiny bit of discussion about unicode characters here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6865/editing-formulas-with-unicode-symbols?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Blackboard bold is for blackboards. What's wrong with real boldface, \bf? Does this work: $\bf1234567890$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not understand why, but  `\mathbb{1234567890}`(rendered code: $\mathbb{1234567890}$)  works for me, and gives the following output

> [image]

If it matters, I'm on a Mac with the latest build of Catalina, viewing the site through Safari. *edit* it seems that the "math renderer" that you are using is important: my web browser is using "HTML-CSS" as the math renderer. (I checked via [right-clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwMNb.jpg) on some rendered MathJax) When I switch to MathML, `\mathbb{1234567890}` also just gives me plain numbers.

Can you see the characters ? I think you can copy-paste them into MathJax code e.g. `$$  ++=^_{^!}$$` gives
$$  ++=^_{^!}$$
I would guess this is not "documented behavior", but Unicode characters in general seem to work in Mathjax e.g. `$\int_{>1}\frac{1}{1+^{100}} d>$`$\int_{>1}\frac{1}{1+^{100}} d>$. What is [documented](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/unicode.html) is the `\unicode{}` command which I learned from the [comments to my answer here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30926/how-can-i-write-backslash-in-mathjax/30929#30929);  it seems that (peeking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold) to find the correct Hex number to use)

```
$\unicode{x1D7D8}\unicode{x1D7D9}\unicode{x1D7DA}\unicode{x1D7DB}\unicode{x1D7DC}\unicode{x1D7DD}\unicode{x1D7DE}\unicode{x1D7DF}\unicode{x1D7E0}\unicode{x1D7E1}$
```

should give you something that works too: $\unicode{x1D7D8}\unicode{x1D7D9}\unicode{x1D7DA}\unicode{x1D7DB}\unicode{x1D7DC}\unicode{x1D7DD}\unicode{x1D7DE}\unicode{x1D7DF}\unicode{x1D7E0}\unicode{x1D7E1}$

PS for my first 20 or so $\LaTeX$ documents I used the following poor substitute that should "work" for everyone (output: $1\!\!12\!\!2 3\!\!3 4\!\!4 5\!\!5 6\!\!6 7\!\!7 8\!\!8 9\!\!9 0\!\!0$)

```
$1\!\!12\!\!2 3\!\!3 4\!\!4 5\!\!5 6\!\!6 7\!\!7 8\!\!8 9\!\!9 0\!\!0$
```

In particular for '1' I had a further variant `$1\hspace{-0.21em}\text l$` $1\hspace{-0.21em}\text l$.

Comment: Safari supports MathML natively -- is that the math renderer you're using?  I believe only Firefox and Safari (still!) currently support MathML and maybe that's the difference?

Comment: @postmortes, Safari tells me that the math renderer is "HTML-CSS". Don't know what it means, but when I switch to MathML, I also get plain numbers for `\mathbb{1234567890}`!

Comment: Thanks :)  That's odd then as none of the browsers (Edge, Chrome, Brave) I have on this Windows 10 system will render the bold numbers properly no what matter renderer I choose

Comment: I think it is documented that Unicode works; in any case it came up at times already. What not few might not realize is how far one can go with this.

Comment: @quid Yeah, I only meant that I couldn't explicitly find it in an admittedly cursory glance/search through the actual documentation of MathJax. I think this "character fallback" might be what's happening http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output/fonts.html?highlight=unicode#character-fallbacks

Comment: @CalvinKhor interesting. It seems from this that it is less of an explicit feature than I thought.

Comment: @postmortes I summarised my findings on that github issue page in your answer, and I got an explanation why it works for me: the HTML-CSS renderer uses my local installation of the "STIX fonts" which come preinstalled on my machine, and these fonts come with blackboard bold lowercase and numbers. I suspect you can replicate this if you install the STIX fonts and use the same renderer. In addition it is planned to work for everyone in MathJax 3 (if/when Math.SE begins to use it)

Answer (score 5):

From this thread, which was the most recent I could find, it looks like it's on the wish-list for MathJax (and has been for a while), but isn't implemented yet.

https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/792

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem of rendering using an OS W8.1. Another simple alternative it to use the command <kbd>\pmb</kbd>+{unicode black board number} as for example:

$$\pmb{,,,,,,,,,}$$